# How to get recent record by a field and ordered by date (complex query)?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to write a method in spring data to get last recod by **text** and ordered by **updateDate**.

My entity look like :

```
@Entity
public class Command {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String text;

    // epoch date
    private Long updateDate;

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

And this is the repository:

```
public interface CommandRepository extends JpaRepository<Command, Long> {
    Command findByTextAndTopByUpdateDateDesc(String text);
}
```

Of course, find by text method must give me more thant one reocord but by filtering with top date will get only one record !

the methode above return the following error :

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property TopByUpdateDateDesc found for type Command!  at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:94)

I tried to check some stackoverflow postes to find any solution but nada !

Is there any solution to that case or i have to use native query ?

Comment: Use `findFirstByTextOrderByUpdateDateDesc`. The `Top`/`First` part should come first, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Comment: Thanx @M. Deinum. could you just put your comment as reponse ? to be able to close the post plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering in your query method is wrong. You first need the limitations (`Top`/`First`) before you do the where part and you end with the ordering. This is also what the error, given a bit cryptic, is telling you.

Instead of `findByTextAndTopByUpdateDateDesc` you should use something like `findFirstByTextOrderByUpdateDateDesc`.

The ordering etc. is explained in the [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) documentation.